# Inheritance in Hibernate OGM

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, hibernate-ogm

How you can handle the inheritance mechanism in Hibernate OGM, in particular using MongoDB? In "Hibernate OGM Reference" I read that the inheritance mechanism is not supported by OGM. So there is a way to avoid the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: what "problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is misleading, inheritance is supported except for `javax.persistence.InheritanceType#JOINED`.

This means that if your model is using `javax.persistence.InheritanceType#SINGLE_TABLE` or `javax.persistence.InheritanceType#TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

You should be fine.

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, I also fixed the documentation. Thanks for the feedback