# Is Hibernate -OGM does not supports InheritanceType.JOINED?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1, hibernate-ogm

Hi i am migrating my application mysql database to mongodb using hibernate-ogm. In my pojo i used  InheritanceType.JOINED ,but i read in documentation "Hibernate OGM supports the following inheritance strategies: * InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS * InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE " and i found as same in following link [Inheritance in Hibernate OGM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933232/inheritance-in-hibernate-ogm) . what is the solution for InheritanceType.JOINED ?I am getting error for InheritanceType.JOINED

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Joined subclasses   strategy not supported
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmPersisterClassResolver.joinedSubclassEntityPersister(OgmPersisterClassResolver.java:32)
```

hibernate-ogm library version 5.0.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only solution at the moment is to use a different type of inheritance mapping.

Feel free to let us know how you would map this strategy in the [Hibernate OGM forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=31).